# Is is possible to set the "aspNetCore requestTimeout" value.........via "code" with Kestrel?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

Is is possible to set the "aspNetCore requestTimeout" value (see xml below).........via "code" with Kestrel?

I cannot find something on the KestrelServerLimits object.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.server.kestrel.core.kestrelserverlimits?view=aspnetcore-3.1

Below is the xml code..........but hoping to do this in CODE, not via (published) xml.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore requestTimeout="00:20:00"  processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" forwardWindowsAuthToken="false"/>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

I tried the below (" serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5); ")......but this does **not** control the server timeout from my postman tests.

```
namespace MyStuff
{
    using System;
    using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
    using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;

    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder =>
                {
                    webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();

                    webBuilder.ConfigureKestrel(serverOptions =>
                    {
                        serverOptions.Limits.KeepAliveTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5);
                    });

                });
    }
}
```

I've been reading from this microsoft article:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?view=aspnetcore-3.1#kestrel-options

> Kestrel options The Kestrel web server has constraint configuration
>   options that are especially useful in Internet-facing deployments.
>
> Set constraints on the Limits property of the KestrelServerOptions
>   class. The Limits property holds an instance of the
>   KestrelServerLimits class.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No. [This GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/10079) says:

> There's no way to forcibly terminate .NET Tasks. This is why we can't stop run-away CPU processes ourselves.

`requestTimeout` in web.config is a timeout for IIS that will stop waiting response from your webapp and return 500 error to client, but your webserver (Kestrel) will continue to process request. And nobody can interrupt it (only restarting kestrel process will help), that's why there is no such configuration setting in kestrel.

Comment: And now I wonder why _anyone_ uses Kestrel as the end-host for ASP.NET Core. Not having a timeout removes a very important safety valve on production environments which can experience unexpected behavior on occasion. This design is as brilliant as using `connection.CommandTimeout = 0`.

Comment: Uhg. It appears that a request timeout is only supported using the IIS _out of process_ model.

Comment: @user2864740 removing the timeout can be useful for real time applications

Comment: @SylvainGantois The core issue is that it’s **not opt-in** to the no-timeout. These “real applications” that are expected to take an excessively long time should be able to *request* more time, **individually**. Otherwise code that takes excessively long is merely faulty. I’ve spent years fixing issues related to the lack of “sanity timeouts”.

Comment: As there are other reasons why code mat fail or be terminated irrecoverably, well written code needs to be able to remain valid regardless of being rudely interrupted. Other generally irrecoverable error cases: loss of network, OOM/SO, power failure, etc.

Comment: what I meant is that some apps need to detect immediately that someone is disconnected, not try to keep the connection alive if its not going to be restored. A real-time game is a good example. You may not want to wait 30s to know that the person has a bad internet connection.

Comment: You can implement this yourself using middleware, or with Polly, or wait for .NET 7 where it's [built-in](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-rate-limiting-for-dotnet/).

Comment: @user2864740 IIS couldn't do it either, though. Whenever it ran into an issue like that, it killed the whole .NET process, killing connectivity for everyone. Timeouts are still there, but they rely on _cooperative_ cancellation (which is the only thing that _can_ work anyway). All of the rude interruptions you listed are handled perfectly fine. Of course, unmanaged CGI didn't have the same problem... but only because it didn't _care_ about the problem - often one timeout would corrupt everyone running in the same process, you just didn't know about it right away.