# ASP.NET Core - identify stuck requests (i.e. infinite loop) and terminate them?

Tags: c#, webapi

I recently debugged a problem where a REST request to an ASP.NET was executing some faulty code in the deserializer that caused the request thread to go into an infinite loop.  The user's request would time out on the client side, but on the server, the infinite loop would continue.  The user would try the request a few more times, and each time this would cause another thread to go into an infinite loop until the machine stopped accepting requests, and we had to restart the server.

I am wondering if there is a way to identify stuck/hanging requests in ASP.NET Core and terminate them, if a problem like this occurs in the future?  I would like to keep problematic requests from destabilizing the rest of the application.

Comment: Depends on how the loop was caused. Can you give a [mre], or maybe a pseudo-code walkthrough?

Comment: I think this question relates to the one [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60640291/is-is-possible-to-set-the-aspnetcore-requesttimeout-value-via-code-w), in which the accepted answer says that there is no built-in way to forcibly close a Task, so you cannot terminate the request execution.